# Use boost build bjam for building Qt stuff

Tags: qt, bjam

I want to extend an existing project which is built by boost-build's bjam with some QT GUI. Now I wanted to know whether there is a good way to do this. Especially: How is the `moc` invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405563&seqNum=3) boost-build V2 suports Qt4 from box.